# How to position a div in laravel with inline css

Tags: css, html

In a laravel view i want to make a relative div that is positioned 50px from the top and 50px from the left.

```
<div style = "position:absolute top:50px right:50px">

 test
</div>
```

Strange thing is this does not work. The image keeps sticking to the top and the left. 
I want to use a inline CSS is this the right way to do it?
If yes then does this have anything to do with laravel?

Comment: miss ";" ? position:absolute; top:50px right:50px

Comment: This is what your code looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/h4B7n/

Comment: change  `right:50px` with  `left:50px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `;` in your styles:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:50px; right:50px;">

 test
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like you sayed you want your DIV `50px from the top and 50px from the left` then change **right** to **left** in your style condition [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9E8DV/1/)

```
<div style = "position:absolute top:50px left:50px">

 test
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

You missed semicolon ( ; ) and replace text right to left for left side position..

```
<div style = "position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;">

 test
</div>
```

Good luck..